# Create Formula field and store month and year seperately two fields

Tags: apex

Need to separate the month and year based on the created date. So I'm planning to create 2 formula fields and whenever the record is created needs to populate the month and year fields based on the Created date. Please let us know the syntax to create the formula field for this. If any alternative way please share it across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it.

```
Month -- VALUE(MONTH( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) ) )
Year -- VALUE(YEAR( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) ) )
```

You can use this formula for month Name

```
CASE(VALUE(MONTH( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) ) ), 1, "January", 2, "February", 3, "March",  4, "April",  5, "May",  6, "June", 7, "July", 8, "August", 9, "September", 10, "October", 11, "November", 12, "December", "None")
```

Comment: Yes Tried. Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Text)

Comment: @techsolutions updated my answer.

Comment: Are you thinking about following lines here: TEXT(YEAR( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) ))

Comment: In month field its storing integer, I would like to store the month like Jan/January like this.